How to make calculate median value for selling_eur if there's quantity/amount column exists in postgresql?
How to calculate median for selling_eur in this table?




id
listing_id
category
amount
original_eur
selling_eur
user_id
rounds_id




0
10088
m1-1579cd77-6863-469d-8798-9e1bef199d2f
Category 2
2
nan
350.11
eu-central-1:6fcfad76-ef06-4ea6-9e14-9fa4a5d62b8f
31


1
10089
m1-2adfde90-de27-4048-aa3e-bc7e76c03b0c
Prime Seats
4
nan
962.81
eu-central-1:6fcfad76-ef06-4ea6-9e14-9fa4a5d62b8f
28


2
10090
m3-024c20ad-e21d-4bb3-966e-44c69e760b15
Category 1
4
200
750
eu-central-1:33d3dbe4-6414-4949-ae21-f2bc8819ae4d
29


3
10091
m1-c612ad6c-d000-4bb5-8dc4-55e3b49d54cd
Category 2
4
150
450
eu-central-1:fe695442-13a6-42e6-a015-046415bf369d
28


4
10092
m1-cd449fb2-6134-428b-946a-fc8a7bec30e7
Category 1
4
nan
647
eu-central-1:b926a781-4fc0-4f71-bd0f-69b50b0be68d
28



Calculate average is quite simle: sum( selling_eur * amount ) / sum ( amount).
But that about median?
Is it simple make arrays with prices, example for 1 row:
{350.1, 350.1}.
And make calculation for this values?

Here's the one with window functions. The subquery adds to each row a range of positions according to the selling_eur order, and from that you can grab the value right below and right above the middle position (floor() and ceil() filters), then divide their sum by two: demo
select sum( selling_eur * amount ) / sum ( amount) as "average"
      ,( max(selling_eur)filter(where floor(middle_index)::int8 <@ int8range)
        +max(selling_eur)filter(where  ceil(middle_index)::int8 <@ int8range)
       )/2. as "median"
from(select *,int8range(sum(amount)over w1 -amount+1,
                        sum(amount)over w1,'[]')
             ,(1.+sum(amount)over())/2. as middle_index
     from your_table
     window w1 as (order by selling_eur) ) as a;




average
median




663.3033333333333333
647.0000000000000000



If the number of elements is even, this will interpolate the two middle elements. If it's odd, it will average out the middle element with itself, so it'll just return that one middle element.

You could repeat your selling_eur exactly amount times in a subquery and feed that to percentile_cont(). Demo at db<>fiddle:
select percentile_cont(.5)within group(order by selling_eur2)
from your_table cross join lateral
(select generate_series(1,amount),selling_eur as selling_eur2);




percentile_cont




647



You can check what percentile_cont() saw and verify that's the median:
select row_number()over(order by selling_eur2)
      ,selling_eur
      ,id
      ,left(listing_id,6) as listing_id
      ,category
      ,amount
      ,n
      ,original_eur
from your_table cross join lateral
(select generate_series(1,amount)n,selling_eur as selling_eur2)
order by selling_eur2;




row_number
selling_eur
id
listing_id
category
amount
n
original_eur




1
350.11
10088
m1-157
Category 2
2
2
NaN


2
350.11
10088
m1-157
Category 2
2
1
NaN


3
450
10091
m1-c61
Category 2
4
1
150


4
450
10091
m1-c61
Category 2
4
4
150


5
450
10091
m1-c61
Category 2
4
3
150


6
450
10091
m1-c61
Category 2
4
2
150


7
647
10092
m1-cd4
Category 1
4
4
NaN


8
647
10092
m1-cd4
Category 1
4
1
NaN


middle value 9
647
10092
m1-cd4
Category 1
4
2
NaN


also middle value 10
647
10092
m1-cd4
Category 1
4
3
NaN


11
750
10090
m3-024
Category 1
4
1
200


12
750
10090
m3-024
Category 1
4
2
200


13
750
10090
m3-024
Category 1
4
3
200


14
750
10090
m3-024
Category 1
4
4
200


15
962.81
10089
m1-2ad
Prime Seats
4
1
NaN


16
962.81
10089
m1-2ad
Prime Seats
4
4
NaN


17
962.81
10089
m1-2ad
Prime Seats
4
3
NaN


18
962.81
10089
m1-2ad
Prime Seats
4
2
NaN




It's fun and it works, but it'll definitely be faster with window functions - if noone beats me to it, I'll post that later.

Zegarek, will this option (with percentile_cont()) work for an even number of rows?

@ValNik It will because it does. If you look at the samples, the amount sums up to an even 18, so what you see is valid output for an even amount. I'm even showing what's fed into the function with the two middle rows highlighted. Here's another demo with an odd total amount. Both of the answers I posted work regardless of whether you're dealing with an odd or even amount.

See example.
Updated query.
with t as(
select *
  ,lead(selling_eur,1,0)over(order by selling_eur) next_selling
  ,sum(amount)over(order by selling_eur)-amount+1 from_amount
  ,sum(amount)over(order by selling_eur) to_amount
  ,sum(amount)over() tot_amount
  ,(sum(amount)over()+1)/2 mean_amount
  ,sum(selling_eur*amount)over() tot_value
from your_table
)
select tot_value/tot_amount avg_value
   ,case when mean_amount= to_amount and (tot_amount/2)=to_amount
        then (selling_eur+next_selling)/2.0
    else selling_eur 
    end as mean_value
from t 
where mean_amount between from_amount and to_amount

fiddle

I'm sorry, but most of this is incorrect: 1) You added an additional record with amount of 4, which shifts the median: in your case it now should be 648, not 647. 2) Even though OP mentioned how they got a correct sum and average, you instead use regular sum() and avg() which won't account for varying amounts. I think you missed the key part where the problem is about the data being pre-aggregated, where instead of pulling stats out of raw, repeated values of selling_eur you get only one of each, with a number of its occurences.

I think, I do not understand this question.OP calculated weighted average, yes.  I will delete answer. Sorry. I will try to understand what is median for  function F(amount,selling_eur) means.

A median is a median. For an odd number of values, it's the middle one. For an even number of values, it's an interpolation between the middle two. The trick here is that OP doesn't have the raw values but rather amounts of those, so the average becomes a weighted average, a sum becomes a sum of values multiplied by their amounts, and the median has to be found also keeping those amounts in mind.

I have completely changed the request. In the previous version (https://dbfiddle.uk/OdW-tiF4), there was a misunderstanding and a mistake. Thanks to @Zegarek for explanation.
